# How long it takes to return to daily activities?

Tags: bone-fractures, fibula, weight-bearing-activity

These are my leg x-ray. I had an accident 7th may 2017. My fibula (hope I got the right name) was fractured. My orthopedist says nothings to worry. It will fine within two weeks. I have passed 12 days, but my legs still pain. If I take pain killer then there is no pain. If I didn’t, it will start the pain.
I have two questions.
Is there is anything’s serious? 
How long it takes to return to daily activities?

[image]

Comment: SE Health is not meant for personal advice. Only your doctor can answer this question based on all the information they have. All in all, pain after 12 days is not very surprising.

Answer (score 1):

Your doctor would be the most qualified to answer this.  I am not able to interpret x-rays, but I do know that fractures usually take 6-8 weeks to heal.  That can differ based on a persons age, nutrition, and whether they have any other underlying health conditions, and the severity of the fracture.  Your doctor who knows your health condition would be able to give you the best estimate based on the variable factors.  Also, after the bone heals the muscles may be tight or weak due to the decrease in activity from the time needed to heal.  This can also contribute to pain.  Don't start exercising until your doctor gives you the OK or you can do more damage than good.